# Creating an app as a Team so both parties can edit code

Tags: ios, swift

My friend and I are creating an app and we are wondering if there is a way where we can both edit the code at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git`! Lets people edit code and track the progress of the project (among many other useful tools).

[Git Tutorial](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

If you are looking for more of a 'Google Docs' atmosphere, I would look into [Codr](http://codr.io) or [Cloud9](https://c9.io)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use SVN. You will see how easy version control could be and later everywhere on the job people will use Git because it is "better" and you will get frustrated.

Just use Git from the beginning, stay happy, you will love it. Really!

The default in Xcode is Git too, so it can't be wrong.

Just be aware that the interface in Xcode is offering you a filtered version of the Git commands. As soon as you really need it for anything you will end up on the command line.

Whatever you try there, the first few times it will fail until you have learned the propper syntax and all side effects. So just make a copy of the folder, or zip or tar it before you try it a simple git command.

Also SourceTree is nice, but same problem there, learn what every command really does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SourceTree a free git repository handler.